# Is there a more formal way of saying "side of an equation"?

Tags: terminology

I've been thinking about it, and the term "side of an equation" (in reference to an equation such as $x^2 + x + 1 = 0$) doesn't seem like a very formal way of trying to describe the expressions on either side of an equal sign.  My reasoning is that with operators such as +, -, /, and *, you have, respectively, the addend, augend, and sum;  minuend, subtrahend, and difference; dividend, divisor, and quotient; and the multiplicand, multiplier, and product.  Despite these being simple operations, there is a more detailed way of expressing each part.  Is there a similar terminology for equations?

Comment: LHS (Left Hand Side) and RHS (Right Hand Side) are some that I have encountered already.

Comment: Unless the expression on one side or the other has a formal name of its own  (like "zero"), it seems that LHS and RHS are formal enough. If  you need to keep mentioning an expression  you can always assign a brief name to it instead of  repeatedly writing it out in full. This is what you are doing when you say LHS or RHS.

Comment: +1 I've never heard the term "augend" before. It's interesting how a commutative operation has different names associated with the two terms.